# ¿Saben por qué repite los datos que ingreso al momento de visualizarlo en un JTextArea?

Tags: java

Este es el código que utilizo y me imprime doble los valores que ingreso en mi arreglo :(

```
JTextArea obj = new JTextArea();
        obj.setText("RFC" + "\t" + "NOMBRE" + "\t" + "EDAD" + "\t" + "DIRECCIÓN" + "\n");
        String cad="";
        
        for(int i=0; i<emp.length; i++){
            if(emp[i][0]!=null){
                cad+= emp[i][0] + "\t" + emp[i][1] + "\t" + emp[i][2] + "\t" + emp[i][3] + "\n";
            }
            obj.append(cad);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj);
        }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿A qué te refieres con que imprime doble? ¿Qué datos hay en el arreglo? ¿Qué debería imprimir? ¿Dónde imprimes? ¿Si trasladas esto dentro del `if`  se resuelve el problema: **`obj.append(cad);`**?

Answer (score 2):

Holaa, lo que pasa es que estas agregando muchos JOptionPane, a al darle ok, crea el siguiente con el texto anterior y se le suma una vez mas el texto, o al menos asi lo entiendo yo, lo probé y funciona correctamente sacando las siguintes lineas fuera del bucle for:

```
obj.append(cad);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj);
```

De este modo quedaría el for

```
for(int i=0; i<emp.length; i++){
   if(emp[i][0]!=null){
      cad+= emp[i][0] + "\t" + emp[i][1] + "\t" + emp[i][2] + "\t" + emp[i][3] + "\n";
   }
 }
 obj.append(cad);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj);
```

Foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡muchas gracias! eres un angel :3